# how to store autocomplete dropdown value(or text in database) on button in mvc using jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

```
<select class="form-control chosen-select " id="SubDepartmentsDDL" name="SubDepartmentsDDL">
   @foreach (var item in Model.abcLists)
   {
        var Role = item.ROLE;
        <option id="grid" value="@Role">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </option>
   }
</select>
<link href="~/pcCSS/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/pcCSS/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/prism.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
        '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
        '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }//,
        //'.chosen-search': {disable_search: false}
    }

    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
</script>
```

I could not store the option selected value, which comes from the database on the button. I don't know how to get that value because when I click on the button it took all values.

```
<input id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info btn-pressure" type="submit" value="Save" title="Click here to Save" />
<div class="col-md-12"></div>
<input id="btnReset" type="button" value="Reset" title="Click here to Reset" class="btn btn-info btn-pressure" onclick="return ConfirmReset();" />
```

Comment: Could you add your `Role` class to question? Basically you cannot put the whole object to value of `option`. If you have got `id` property you can put it into `option` values and then find the selected `Role` by its `id`

Comment: public class Roles
    {
      
        public string ROLE { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    
        public string abc { get; set; }
        public string efg { get; set; }
        public string flpi { get; set; }
        public decimal Oerno { get; set; }
        public string mnbv { get; set; }
        public string zaqw { get; set; }
    }

Comment: your right sir but i am not getting selected value and i tried to store it by id but it did not take single value. i am getting only searchable dropdown but i dont know how to store it on button in mvc

Comment: Could you add this info to the question? So `Role.ROLE` would identify role correct? Remove `id="grid"` from `<option id="grid" value="@Role">` as you would get several option with one ID.

Comment: its general info like general manager,software engineer,software tester thats my ROLE i removed my id but still not getting one value but i dont want to use hard coded value please help me sir